# how to use multiple <http> configurations

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have two file with `<http>` element. Those two have different configurations.

```
<http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
```

and

```
<http path-type="regex" auto-config="false" realm="Protected API" use-expressions="true" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="CustomAPIAuthenticationEntryPoint">
```

but in deployment I get error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Duplicate  element detected
>   Offending resource: class path resource [websecurity-http.xml]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:72)

I'm using `spring-3.0.7`. Is there a way I can use two different `<http>` configurations. I have **two** `websecurity.xml` files here

Comment: Yes you can but they have to have different url patterns. You cannot have 2 different http elements for the exact same url patterns.

Comment: ..yes, i think this conflict is due to the fact, that both `<http>`s (effectively) have `pattern=""`

Comment: @xerx593 `<http>` element don't have pattern attribute. Are you referring to `<intercept-url>` `pattern` attribute? they are different in two files.

Comment: @M.Deinum Are you referring to `<intercept-url>` `pattern` attribute? they are different in two files.

Comment: No I'm referring to the `pattern` attribute of the `http` element. They need to differ. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-minimal. They now both have `pattern="/**"` due to not being present.

Comment: Here, me , too, but also applying to elder spring-security verison(s): e.g. [v3.1](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html)

Comment: thanks for the comments. `spring-3.1.0` and higher have the `pattern` attribute for `<http>`. I had to upgrade spring version. now it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @M. Deinum and @xerx593 suggested we can use `<http pattern=""/>` for this.

I was using `spring-3.0.7`. But [spring introduce multiple `<http>` element feature in `spring-3.1.0`](https://www.infoq.com/news/2011/12/spring-security-3.1). So I had to upgrade spring.